How to process Python Polars LazyFrame in batches
I would like to lazy load a large parquet file. I then need to process it in batches because I'm writing into a database, and there is a limit to how many rows can be written to the database at once. LazyFrame has no write_database method, so I'm collecting batches into a dataframe to use DataFrame.write_database.
The problem is that collecting the dataframe takes longer as I work through the batches using LazyFrame.slice, but only for certain datasets. All datasets are two columns. If both columns in the frame are strings and there are about 50 million rows, collecting is fairly consistently fast: the first collect takes ~0.02 seconds, and subsequent collects take about 1.5 seconds. But if one column is i64 and there are about 100 million rows, the first collect is fast at ~0.02 seconds, but subsequent collect operations take 10+ seconds, and the computer's RAM usage goes up. The estimated size of the various dataframe batches is about the same across datasets: 7-8MB.
Here's simplified code:
lf = pl.scan_parquet(file)

n_batch = 100_000
row = 0

while row < 500_000:
    lf_batch = lf.slice(row, n_batch)
    df_batch = lf_batch.collect()
    df_batch.write_database(…)
    row += n_batch

Is there a better way to collect batches?

You could try breaking the frame by row count like in this answer:
splitting-a-lazyframe-into-two-frames-by-fraction-of-rows-to-make-a-train-test-s-set
Although you would need to calculate the number of dataframes needed before hand.
